# Code is not executing inside asyncTask when it called from unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-asynctask, mocking

I have function which executes some task inside the asynctask.

Below is my function:

```
    void create() {
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.v("inside run", "inside run");
            }
        });
    }
```

I have written the unit test for the above method and ran the test.

The create() function is getting called but inside run is not getting called.

My Unit test is:

```
    @Test
    public void createTest() {
        mMockedManager.create();
    }
```

The way i written the uint test is correct?
If not what is the way to write the unit test for the above method?

Thanks!!!